# is this correct; using lighted rather than lit?

Tags: american-english, british-english

Please help me clarify if this usage of the word "lighted" is correct in the following statement. "I have lighted the candle"

Comment: No, that's not correct.

Comment: Correction. It's not incorrect, as a quick look in say AHDEL, Collins or RHK Webster's will show you.  But it's an old-fashioned to archaic usage of 'lighted'.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Some verbs have two accepted past tense forms, and "light" is one of them. However, people who are used to the other form might think it sounds funny, as Ian MacDonald's comment indicates.